# How can I specify column name casing in TypeORM migrations

Tags: sql, postgresql, typescript, migration, typeorm

I'm using typeORM and I want to use migrations instead of syncing because I'm working in a team and it's actually a lot of tedious work to get the db to a state in which the app actually functions.

The problem is that every column name I specify in the migration gets converted to lowercase which I've worked around by making all entity props snake_case. But foreign keys get converted to camelCase by (I think) postgres by default so I can't relate anything to each other by foreign key in my migration. (because it needs to be camelCase but the query gets converted to lowercase)

Have i made clear what my problem is?

Is there a way to solve this, or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

An alternative to allow TypeOrm to support conversion from camelCase to snake_case can be achieved by adjusting your ormconfig.js to support the [Typeorm Naming Strategies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeorm-naming-strategies) package. This will allow you to have coding convention within the code and database naming convention within the database.

It can be set up by:

```
npm i --save typeorm-naming-strategies
```

Then within your ormconfig.js, add the following lines:

```
const SnakeNamingStrategy = require('typeorm-naming-strategies')
  .SnakeNamingStrategy;

module.exports = {
    name: 'development',
    type: 'postgres',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5432,
   ...
   namingStrategy: new SnakeNamingStrategy(),
}
```

TypeOrm will now follow the snake_case convention when naming columns within postgres

Comment: This should be an accepted answer, great!

Answer (score 6):

In postgresql, column and table names are automatically converted to lowercase unless you include them in double quotes:

```
columnName becomes columnname
"columnName" remains as columnName
```

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html -- "Quoting an identifier also makes it case-sensitive, whereas unquoted names are always folded to lower case."

So you should write migrations as, for example,

```
ALTER TABLE "tableName" ADD COLUMN "columnName" character varying ...
```

and queries similarly.