# NestJs - camelCase to snake_case

Tags: nestjs, class-transformer

Frontend passes payload in camelCase to backend (nestjs) that contains DTO in snake case. What is the recommended way to handle this?

One can certainly do from the answer of (this)[ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59938016/typescript-transform-camelcase-keys-to-snake-case]
, is there a better and neat solution at all?

Tried the below but noticed `Expose` in class transformer seemed to never have worked as expected from https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/issues/722.

```
{
...
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Expose({name: "employeeCount"})
  employee_count: string;

}
```

I tried to use a getter but that returned undefined.

```
{
...
  @IsNotEmpty()
  employeeCount: string;

  get employee_count(): number {
    return +this.employeeCount;
}
```

Comment: I guess you can use the getter but you will need to enable `transformation` at `ValidationPipe`

Comment: The `@Expose()` should work, but like Micael mentioned, the `transform` option of the `ValidationPipe` needs to be set to `true`

Answer (score 0):

At this point, it might be impossible to refactor. However, since it is not ideal to keep column names in camelCase, I suggest you to refactor entities by passing snake_case naming convensions through the properties for long-term productivity;

```js
  @Column({
    type: 'varchar',
    length: 50,
    name: 'full_name',
    default: null,
  })
  @IsString()
  fullName: string;
```

> Caution! Typeorm will delete the old columns and add the new ones with default values, by default.

Another option might be defining a custom logic for value transformation. To serialize camaleCse to snake_case, use toPlainOnly option in custom transformer logic:

```js
  @Transform(value => value, { toPlainOnly: true })
  fullName: string;
```

Of course, it must be handle around of [nestjs serialization techniques](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/serialization#transform) by builtin interceptor, mostly in global scope.

Answer (score 0):

As detailed here -- [How can I specify column name casing in TypeORM migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52931663/how-can-i-specify-column-name-casing-in-typeorm-migrations), one way to do this would be to add the naming strategies package ...

```
npm i --save typeorm-naming-strategies
```

and then specify the naming strategy within TypeORM ...

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import * as dotenvExpand from 'dotenv-expand';
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';

const SnakeNamingStrategy = require('typeorm-naming-strategies')
  .SnakeNamingStrategy;
  
dotenvExpand.expand(dotenv.config());

export default new DataSource({
  type: 'postgres',
  host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
  port: Number(process.env.DATABASE_PORT) || 5432,
  database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
  username: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  entities: ['dist/**/*.entity.js'],
  migrations: ['dist/database/migrations/*.js'],
  extra: {
    charset: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
  },
  namingStrategy: new SnakeNamingStrategy(),
 });
```